# IBM Watson Assistant: Regular expressions with context variables

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am gathering some context variables with slots, and they work just fine. [image]

So I decided to do in another node of the conversation, check if one of these context variables is a specific number:

I was thinking on enabling multi-responses and check if, for example `$dni:1` (it is an integer, pattern of 1 integer only), or if it is 2 or 3:

[image]

But this is not working. I was trying to solve it for some days with different approaches but I really cannot find a way through it.

My guess is that a context variable has a value, and you can print it to use it like responding with the user's name and stuff like that (which indeed is useful!), but comparing values is not possible.

Any insights on this I can receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watson Assistant uses a short-hand syntax but also supports the more complex expressions. What you could do is to edit the condition in the JSON editor. There, for the condition, use a function like [matches()](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#string-matches-string-regexp-) on the value of the context variable.

Note that [it is not recommended to check for context variables in the slot conditions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots#dialog-slots-add). You can use multi-responses. An alternative way is to put the check into the response itself. There, you can [use predicates to generate the answer](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response).

```
<? context.dni==1 ? 'Very well' : 'Your number is not 1' ?>
```

You can nest the evaluation to have three different answers. Another way is to build an array of responses and use **dni** as key.

Instead of matching to specific integers, you could consider using the [Numbers system entity](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-sys-number). Watson Assistant supports several languages. As a benefit, users could answer "the first one", "the 2nd option", etc., and the bot still would understand and your logic could still route to the correct answer.

Comment: I see, but I am not checking them in slots, but multi-response, right? I use slots to fill in all the variables (the user actually does not fill anything, he just inputs his id, and internally, I output in watson all the vars checking in a db). Also, `matches()`'s link is broken (or I [can't see it](https://gyazo.com/a41fa760e4e3492d539d01aafe8a2c3f).

Comment: The link behind `matches()` works for me. Try this one as base URI: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods

Using slots to fill in the variables is OK. Correct that you should use multi-responses or a single response with some logic. What is your overall goal? I am using a backend database in this tutorial https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#build-a-database-driven-slackbot

Comment: Not working still the link! I'll look in ibm docs manually, don't worry!

About the main goal, the user has this `dni`(one integer with pattern `\d`), that depending on the value, the bot should respond differently. If it is 1, `X`, if 2, `Y`, if 3 `Z`. For example: 1: ' _you do not have X service included_ ' , 2: ' _you have some of it included_ ', 3: ' _you have all included!_ ' .

Comment: I added more details. The links are based on https://cloud.ibm.com and then navigating to the docs and the WA service.

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer as it would probably solve all questions related to this! I'll keep trying with what you told me, which probably will get it! Thanks a lot in advanced! If it is no bother, I'll coment in here if I cannot manage it!